# Como alterna entre Lista e Galeria

Tags: javascript, html, css

O que pretendo criar, é semelhante a **Grid view** utilizado em sistemas do tipo `Mercado Livre`. Seria uma função feito em javascript que alterna entre uma ***Lista*** ou ***Galeria***, utilizando os mesmos dados em forma de tabela.

> **Expondo a dúvida** - Suponho mostrar *screenshot* de jogos em flash com suas respectivas informações a frente, em *modo* **Lista**. Contudo se o usuário não deseja ver em *modo* **Lista**, após o clique no botão, como agrupa-los novamente dentro da página em *modo* **Galeria**?

Então, estou buscando num só código fazer as duas coisas distintas, algo como:

```
if(condição)
{
     ...
    Lista
     ...
   }else{
     ...
    Grade
     ...
}
```

> A princípio, imagino que poderia ser divs retangulares que, ao clicar no botão elas redimensiona o tamanho para quadrados, pondo-se lado a lado.

Comment: Não faço ideia do que é um código ou função "Lista/Galeria"... podes explicar melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diego, defina os elementos que serão exibidos em cada grupo, no exemplo abaixo eu chamei o grupo de `card` e cada card possui uma `imagem`, `titulo` e `desc`.

então defina o espaço onde as `card` vão ser exibidas, no exemplo abaixo estou limitando o espaço delas pela `div#container`.

defina uma classe para cada tipo de exibição, novamente vamos utilizar apenas `lista` e `grid`, mas você pode definir quantos modelos desejar.

defina um tamanho para a `card` para cada disposição do container, no exemplo abaixo temos:

```
div#container.lista: .card{ width: calc(100% -10px); height: 128px; }
div#container.grid: .card { width: 192px; height: 192px; }
```

agora faça o mesmo para possicionar cada elemento (`div.image`, `div.title`, `div.desc`) da `card` na posição correta.

agora basta trocar a classe da `div#container` para mudar o layout.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var disposicao = document.querySelector("#disposicao");
var curClass = container.classList.contains("lista") ? "lista" : "grid";

disposicao.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  container.classList.remove(curClass);
  curClass = disposicao.value;
  container.classList.add(curClass);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 1080px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}

#disposicao {
  width: 100%;
}

.card .imagem  {
  background-image: url('http://image005.flaticon.com/1/png/512/119/119706.png');
  background-size: calc(100% - 10px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.lista .card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 128px;  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.lista .card .imagem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.lista .card .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.lista .card .desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid .card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 192px;
  height: 320px;  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.grid .card .imagem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.grid .card .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 192px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 192px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}

.grid .card .desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 222px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 192px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container lista">
  <div>
    <select id="disposicao">
      <option value="lista">Lista</option>
      <option value="grid">Grid</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imagem"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Descrição</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imagem"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Descrição</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imagem"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Descrição</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imagem"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Descrição</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imagem"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Descrição</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card">
    <div class="imagem"></div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="desc">Descrição</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em continuidade, a reposta de [Tobias Mesquita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127544/41467) que mostrou ser prático na forma como um **List/Grid view** se comporta, no que diz à respeito a elementos estilizados com *CSS*.

Não podia eu, ficar sem compartilhar a minha resposta como sempre faço. E quando o faço, é para deixar claro que alcancei o objetivo.

Neste caso, pondo o exemplo da resposta dada acima sobre teste em alguns navegadores obsoleto, houve algumas falhas(entre um caso e outro, estava o CSS ou Javascript a não funcionar conforme o esperado), já que alguns navegadores de internet não suporta tal semântica moderna.

Cheguei a conclusão de que seria viável escrever um novo código compativel com diversos Navegadores de Internet(antigos e atuais), **reaproveitando particularidades do conceito** dado na resposta de [Tobias Mesquita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127544/41467).

Em função disto, utilizei o Firefox 2.0 como base. Vejamos o código abaixo:

```js
    function changeSrc(id){

    <!-- A variável "el" esta apontando para a div mestre, pela "TagName".  Tendo controle sobre ela o botão de alternância, ondeá faz de certo modo as divs se auto ajustar -->
    var el=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; var imagem=document.getElementById(id); if(imagem.alt == "Abrir"){ imagem.src = "http://sl.uploads.im/t/yx4Ig.png"; imagem.alt = "Fechar"; el.className = "grade"; } else { imagem.src = "http://sm.uploads.im/t/sRShv.png"; imagem.alt = "Abrir"; el.className = "lista"; } }
```

```css
/* Aqui inicializa a estilização do layout "Lista" */ .item img { width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; margin-top:-50px; margin-left:-50px; } .lista .item { position: relative; margin: 5px; width: 100%; height: 128px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black; border-radius: 3px; } .lista .item .foto { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 128px; height: 128px; border-right: 1px solid silver; background-color: whitesmoke; } .lista .item .nome { position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: 128px; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; padding-left: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid silver; font-weight: bold; display: block; font-size: 14pt; } .lista .item .desc { position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 128px; padding: 5px; display: block; font-size: 12pt; } /* A partir daqui, é a estilização do layout "Grade" */ .grade .item { float: left; position: relative; left: 90px; width: 192px; height: 320px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black; border-radius: 3px; } .grade .item .foto { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 192px; height: 192px; border-bottom: 1px solid silver; background-color: whitesmoke; } .grade .item .nome { position: absolute; top: 192px; height: 32px; width: 192px; left: 0px; line-height: 32px; padding-left: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid silver; font-weight: bold; display: block; font-size: 14pt; } .grade .item .desc { position: absolute; top: 222px; bottom: 0px; width: 192px; left: 0px; padding: 5px; display: block; font-size: 12pt; }
```

```html
<!-- Abaixo é esta a primeira div, logo no início, sem "id" ou "class" alguma. Ela  é a div mestre, fará com que as demais em seu interior sejam obrigatoriamente redimensionadas e alojadas -->
<!-- Isto se faz necessário para não precisar acrescentar códigos Javascript à mais no documento HTML, bastando apenas uma única div. -->
<!-- Se não fosse assim, logo teríamos de  cria vários ids ou names para cada uma das divs filhos e percorrer com um laço for -->

<div>

<!-- Nesta parte temos a div classificada como lista, que por sua vez  nos traz todo o conjuto de divs estilizada dentro do documento HTML -->
<div class="lista">

    <!-- Logo abaixo temos a tag img que será nosso único botão que alternar entre a opção Lista e Grade -->
    <img id="botao" alt="Abrir" src="http://sm.uploads.im/t/sRShv.png" onclick="changeSrc('botao')" />

    <hr>

    <!-- As alterações principais são feitas aqui, onde as letras do alfabeto que foram tidas como exemplo, deverão ser subtituídas pela tag image -->

    <!-- Nota! - Para a descrição é recomendado no mínimo 170 caracteres(digitos) ou no máximo 177 caracteres(digitos), dentro desta caixa -->
    <!-- Uma vez ultrapassado este limite dado, o usuário final terá uma visualização desagradável, texto exposto. -->
    <!-- Caso deseje por mais informações, o ideal é ajustar a mesma com novos valores em sua margem, no código CSS -->

    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">A</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">B</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">C</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">D</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">E</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">F</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">G</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="foto">H</div>
        <div class="nome">Titulo</div>
        <div class="desc">Descricao</div>
    </div>
```

Enfim, quando você projeta com *CSS* precisa ter a habilidade de analisar o layout e decidir como colocar as `div`.

**Foi por causa desta minha dificuldade em racionar `div` que fiz à pergunta**.

Este outro exemplo abaixo, é ainda menor e portátil se comparado ao anterior.

A única diferença entre um e outro, fica por conta da estrutura *CSS* e *Javascript*. Veja:

```js
function ativar(tag) {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for (var i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].className == "menos") {
            document.getElementById("clic").innerHTML = "Grade";
            el[i].className = "mais";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("clic").innerHTML = "Lista";
            el[i].className = "menos";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
    /* Ajusta para o modo Lista(Tabela) */

    .mais {
        width: auto;
    }

    /* Ajusta para o modo Grade(Galeria) */

    .menos {
        width: 128px;
    }

    /* Estiliza o Menu(botão) */

    a:link {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a:visited {
        color: navy;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: dodgerblue;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:active {
        color: azure;
        text-decoration: underline;
        background-color: dodgerblue;
    }

    /* Fim Estilização do Menu */

    /* Estilização do Corpo da Página */

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    /* Estiliza o Parágrafo da Descrição */

    p {
        line-height: 20px
    }

    /* Estiliza os bloco de conteudo */

    #bloco {
        margin-left: 5%;
        float: left;
        left: 65%;
    }

    /* Estiliza os blocos que mantém as figura */

    #figura {
        background: whitesmoke;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 5px;
        float: left;
    }

    /* Estiliza os blocos que mantém as figura */

    #conteudo {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 5px;
        left: 35%;
    }
```

```html
<center>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ativar(this)" id="clic">Lista</a>

</center>

<hr color="royalblue" size="1" width="100%" />

</br>

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 1 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 2 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 3 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 4 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 5 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 6 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 7 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 8 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
   </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 9 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->

<div id="bloco">
    <div id="figura">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/128/96/" border="0" />
  </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /figura -->
    <div id="conteudo">
        <h3>Titulo 0 </h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sodales ultricies venenatis. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /conteudo -->
</div>
<!-- /bloco -->
```

O código em si esta bem comentado e são auto-explicativo, não havendo qualquer dúvida, termino por aqui.